# Fill in using unique values in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3, 1, 3, np.nan, 3], 'name': ['A','A', 'B','B','B','B', 'C','C','C']})

  name  value
0    A      1
1    A    NaN
2    B    NaN
3    B      2
4    B      2
5    B      2
6    C      3
7    C    NaN
8    C      3
```

In the dataframe above, I want to use groupby to fill in the missing values for each group (based on the `name` column) using the `unique` value for each group. It is gauranteed that each group will have a single unique value apart from NaNs. How do I do that?

Comment: `df['value'] = df.groupby('name')['value'].transform('first')` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake in your dummy dataframe if we refer to your illustration, so I modified it.

**Other solution proposed**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 2, 2, 3, np.nan, 3], 
                   'name': ['A','A', 'B','B','B','B', 'C','C','C']})

r  = (df.groupby('name')
        .apply(lambda g: g.fillna([x for x in g['value'].unique() if x == x][0]))
       )

print(r)
```

```
   value name
0    1.0    A
1    1.0    A
2    2.0    B
3    2.0    B
4    2.0    B
5    2.0    B
6    3.0    C
7    3.0    C
8    3.0    C
```

**Explanation**

This code is based on the following properties

```py
>>> import numpy as np
3 == 3
True
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
```